# How to control animation speed (requestAnimationFrame)?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I change the text color with `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` function:

```
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  ... // change text color here
  if (offset_s < offset_e) {requestAnimationFrame(animate);}
}
```

`offset_s` and `offset_s` indicates start and end positions of the text for color change. In some cases the animation should last for 2 seconds, but in order cases - for 5 seconds, but `offset_e - offset_s` could be the same in these two cases. What can I do to control the speed of animation based on given time in seconds/milliseconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling fps with requestAnimationFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764018/controlling-fps-with-requestanimationframe)

Comment: if you're only changing the color you could use a css animation, it's easier to control time with it

Answer (score 4):

From the tags of the question i can only see that you animate something drawn on canvas and thats why u cannot use css-animation or jquery-animation.

You have to control the length of the animation by calculating the time difference.

u can do it similar to this example

```
function start_animate(duration) {
  var requestID;
  var startTime =null; 
  var time ;   

  var animate = function(time) {


   time = new Date().getTime(); //millisecond-timstamp

   if (startTime === null) {
        startTime = time;
   }
   var progress = time - startTime;

   if (progress < duration ) {

       if(offset_s < offset_e){
         // change text color here

       }
       requestID= requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   } 
   else{
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
   }
   requestID=requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
}
```

trigger your animation and call  start_animate(2000)   //duration in millisecond  1000=1 sec

Answer (score 2):

You should separate concerns clearly.
Have a single requestAnimationFrame running, which computes the current animation time and calls every update and draw related functions.
Then your animations would be handled by a function (or class instance if you go OOP) that deals with the current animation time.

Just some direction for the code :

```
var animationTime = -1;
var _lastAnimationTime = -1;

function launchAnimation() {
    requestAnimationFrame(_launchAnimation);
}    

function _launchAnimation(time) {
    animationTime = 0;
    _lastAnimationTime = time;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(time){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  var dt = time - _lastAnimationTime ;
  _lastAnimationTime = time;
  animationTime += dt;

  // here call every draw / update functions
  //  ...
  animationHandler.update(animationTime);
  animationHandler.draw(context);
}
```

To start your 'engine', just call `launchAnimation` then you'll have a valid `animationTime` and `dt` to deal with.

I'd make `animationHandler` an instance of an `AnimationHandler` class, that allows to add/remove/update/draw animations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use setInterval function in JavaScript.

`requestAnimationFrame` really needs some 'ugly' calculations. Don't 
believe me? Scroll up, you will see...

So, to make `setInterval` function as handy as rAF(requestAnimationFrame) store the function inside of variable. Here is an example:

```
var gameLoop = setInterval(function() {
  update();
  draw();
  if (gameOver)
    clearInterval(gameLoop);
}, 1000/FPS);
```

given way, you can control your FPS and pick correct velocity for your objects.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like

**es6**

```
constructor() {
    this.draw();
}

draw() {
    const fps30 = 1000 / 30;
    const fps60 = 1000 / 60;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setTimeout(this.draw.bind(this), fps30);
    });
}
```

**es5**

```
function DrawingProgram() {
    this.draw();
}

DrawingProgram.prototype.draw = function() {
    var fps30 = 1000/30;
    var fps60 = 1000/60;
    var self = this;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            self.draw(); // you could also use apply/call here if you want
        }, fps30)
    });
}
```