# How to make class method recursion for gaming loops?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, recursion

i have this code:

```
export default class Main {
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | null;

  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;

  constructor() {
    this.canvas = null;
    this.context = null;
  }

  init() {
    this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop);

    return () => { };
  }

  draw() {
    const randomColor = Math.random() > 0.5 ? '#ff8080' : '#0099b0';
    this.context.fillStyle = randomColor;
    this.context.fillRect(100, 50, 200, 175);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  gameLoop(timestamp: number) {
    this.draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop);
  }

  core() {
    window.onload = this.init();
  }
}

const main = new Main();
main.core();
```

the error i receive is:
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.draw')
gameLoop (main.ts:19)

but actually if I log `this` inside gameLoop i get `undefined` which makes sense because gameLoop is called innerly by requestAnimationFrame, not by my `Main` class.
and because of the same problem, `this.draw` is undefined.

how to fix that?

Comment: You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method to your class or use an arrow function notation. `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this));`. Looking for a dupe question right now

Comment: probably there is a dupe question but i couldn't find either, so i made one myself. ill do this binding thing. Thanks.

Comment: Best I could find is ['this' is undefined in JavaScript class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59060545/3257622) which has some usefull answers. Not sure if full dupe but it may point others in the right direction.

Comment: ya, not exactly what was delighted in this question, but useful surely. But i think its better to keep this question alive tho. Could you post answer so I can apply as answer?

Comment: FYI, [there's no recursion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181253/is-requestanimationframe-implementations-recursive/66736179#66736179).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method to your class to make sure `this` points to your class.

```js
class Main {
  canvas;
  context;
  
  init() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this));
  }

  draw() {
    const randomColor = Math.random() > 0.5 ? '#ff8080' : '#0099b0';
    this.context.fillStyle = randomColor;
    this.context.fillRect(100, 50, 200, 175);
  }
  
  gameLoop(timestamp) {
    this.draw();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this));
  }

  core() {
    window.onload = this.init();
  }
}

const main = new Main();
main.core();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```