# how to include a sleep function in Yew app?

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

I am trying to build small application with Yew (Rustwasm) . I would like to put sleep function in Yew app.when I use use std::thread::sleep , I am getting below error

I am using sleep as below

```
let mut index = 0;
sleep(Duration::new(1, 0));
if col < 3 {
    index = row * 4 + (col + 1);
    if self.cellule[index].value == 1 {
        sleep(Duration::new(1, 0));
```

```
wasm.js:314 panicked at 'can't sleep', src/libstd/sys/wasm/thread.rs:26:9

Stack:

Error
    at imports.wbg.__wbg_new_59cb74e423758ede (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm.js:302:19)
    at console_error_panic_hook::hook::hd38f373f442d725c (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[117]:0x16a3e)
    at core::ops::function::Fn::call::hf1476807b3d9587d (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[429]:0x22955)
    at std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hb07b303a83b6d242 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[211]:0x1ed0d)
    at std::panicking::begin_panic::h97f15f2442acdda4 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[321]:0x21ee0)
    at std::sys::wasm::thread::Thread::sleep::hdd97a2b229644713 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[406]:0x22829)
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, you can't.

Comment: Related: [When compiling Rust to wasm (web assembly), how can I sleep for 10 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765987/when-compiling-rust-to-wasm-web-assembly-how-can-i-sleep-for-10-milliseconds)

Comment: is there anyway bring sleep functionality before rendering the components in Yew apps ?

Comment: It's really nice that you get the `'can't sleep'` message. I'm using WASM with a pure JS frontend and just get the stack trace.. does anybody know how to get these messages too?

Answer (score 2):

The methods like `thread::sleep` doesn't work, because in the JS environment you have a single thread only. If you call that sleep you will block the app completely.

If you want to use an interval you should "order" a callback. You can check the following example how to use `TimeoutService` or `IntervalService` for that: [yew/examples/timer](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/master/examples/timer/src/main.rs)

The core idea to create a service this way:

```
let handle = TimeoutService::spawn(
    Duration::from_secs(3),
    self.link.callback(|_| Msg::Done),
);
// Keep the task or timer will be cancelled
self.timeout_job = Some(handle);
```

Now you can use handler of `Msg::Done` to react to that timer elapsed.

> Threads are actually available, but it's a complex topic and you have to use `Web Workers API` reach them. Anyway it's useless for your case. Also there are some proposals in standards, but they aren't available in the browsers yet.