# Replay canvas drawing with line smoothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Write your name in the canvas below, the code saves the drawing `coordinates` in the array. then I want to replay the drawing using this `coordinates` but it doesn't work. I think the issue is it draws it fast!!

How would you do this?

[Here is a sample of what we want](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/record-and-playback-drawing-in-html5-canvas/).

```js
const coordinates = [];

document.getElementById('coordinatesBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(coordinates)
});


document.getElementById('coordinatesDrawBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  play()
});

let step = 0;

function play() {

  steps();

  function steps() {

    draw(null, coordinates[step].x, coordinates[step].y);
    step++;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(steps);

  }
}


var surface, ctx, target, inProgress, cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, skip1, skip2;

function $(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e);
}

function draw(e, aa, bb) {
  var x = e ? e.offsetX : aa;
  var y = e ? e.offsetY : bb;

  target.x.innerHTML = x;
  target.y.innerHTML = y;

  coordinates.push({
    x,
    y
  });

  //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  if (!inProgress) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    inProgress = true;
    skip1 = true;
    skip2 = false;
  } else {
    if (skip1) {
      cp1x = x;
      cp1y = y;
      skip1 = false;
      skip2 = true;
    }
    if (skip2) {
      cp2x = x;
      cp2y = y;
      skip1 = false;
      skip2 = false;
    } else {
      //ctx.lineTo(x,y);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
      //ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, x, y);
      skip1 = true;
      skip2 = false;
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function captureTouch() {
  surface.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    $('msg').style.setProperty('display', 'none');
    surface.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    surface.removeEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
    inProgress = false;
    ctx.save();
  }, false);
}

function init() {
  surface = $('surface');
  surface.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  surface.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx = surface.getContext('2d');
  target = {
    x: $('x'),
    y: $('y')
  };
  captureTouch();
  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#msg {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#coords{ 
    background:#ffc; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #fc0;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
}
#surface {
    background:white;
}
.tp{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:#999;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset white 0 0 15px 5px, white 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Draw</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="coords">
            <div id="msg">Start drawing!</div>
            X: <span id="x"></span>
            Y: <span id="y"></span>
        </div>
        <button id="coordinatesBtn">Show coordinates of drawing</button>
         <button id="coordinatesDrawBtn">Use coordinates to draw</button>
        <div id="container">
            <canvas id="surface"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Separate the part that adds the dot to the canvas into its own function called `add` (for example), and for both the `play` and `draw` functions call it with the current coordinates.
2. Assign the canvas to a variable so that you can reset it prior to drawing the saved image.
3. Only run the animation while `step` < `coordinates.length`.

```js
// Cache the canvas element
const canvas = document.querySelector('#surface');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const coordinates = [];

document.getElementById('coordinatesBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(coordinates)
});

document.getElementById('coordinatesDrawBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  play()
});

let step = 0;

function play() {

  // Clear the canvas element before
  // writing a new image
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  steps();

  function steps() {

    // Call the `add` function with
    // the current coords
    add(coordinates[step].x, coordinates[step].y);

    step++;

    // Stop the animation if the end of the array
    // is reached
    if (step < coordinates.length) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(steps);
    }
  }
}


var surface, ctx, target, inProgress, cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, skip1, skip2;

function $(e) {
  return document.getElementById(e);
}

function draw(e, aa, bb) {
  var x = e ? e.offsetX : aa;
  var y = e ? e.offsetY : bb;

  target.x.innerHTML = x;
  target.y.innerHTML = y;

  coordinates.push({
    x,
    y
  });

  // Call add with the current coords
  add(x, y);
}

// New function `add` that adds the dot
// to the canvas
function add(x, y) {
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  if (!inProgress) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    inProgress = true;
    skip1 = true;
    skip2 = false;
  } else {
    if (skip1) {
      cp1x = x;
      cp1y = y;
      skip1 = false;
      skip2 = true;
    }
    if (skip2) {
      cp2x = x;
      cp2y = y;
      skip1 = false;
      skip2 = false;
    } else {
      //ctx.lineTo(x,y);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
      //ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, x, y);
      skip1 = true;
      skip2 = false;
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

function captureTouch() {
  surface.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    $('msg').style.setProperty('display', 'none');
    surface.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
  }, false);
  surface.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    surface.removeEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
    inProgress = false;
    ctx.save();
  }, false);
}

function init() {
  surface = $('surface');
  surface.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  surface.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx = surface.getContext('2d');
  target = {
    x: $('x'),
    y: $('y')
  };
  captureTouch();
  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#msg {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#coords {
  background: #ffc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fc0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#surface {
  background: white;
}

.tp {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset white 0 0 15px 5px, white 0 0 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="coords">
    <div id="msg">Start drawing!</div>
    X: <span id="x"></span> Y: <span id="y"></span>
  </div>
  <button id="coordinatesBtn">Show coordinates of drawing</button>
  <button id="coordinatesDrawBtn">Use coordinates to draw</button>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="surface"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Comment: What a great job!! Bravo.. But as you noted when you write Andy with separate characters the play results in continues Andy right? any improvement?

Comment: I guess play around with some of the settings in `add`. Maybe drop the `ctx.lineWidth` down to `1`, comment out the `shadowBlur` line. Have a play around and see what works. I don't have a lot of experience working with `requestAnimationFrame` but [it looks like you can throttle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764018/controlling-fps-with-requestanimationframe) which might make it smoother (if that's what you were referring to.)

Comment: Please read the updated comment above, there is a bug in the code..

Comment: _"But as you noted when you write Andy with separate characters"_: where did I write that?

Comment: Sorry, if you write Andy... Language barriers!!!

Comment: Hah, I understand. I'm just about to head out so can't write an update to my answer but I will point you in the right direction. At the moment you have one array that's create when you `mousedown`. For individual letters you'll probably want to create a main array and add a _new_ array to it when you `mouseup` and then `mousedown` again. And then it's a matter of iterating over the nested arrays to ensure that you get the right output. Have a go yourself, and if you run into problems, post the code again as a new question and I'm sure someone will take a look.

Comment: Thanks, So I choose you answer... try myself and if create new question..

Comment: Please don't remove your comments they could be a reference for me..